# jdbc-template ORA-00942 table or view does not exist

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, jdbc, hikaricp

I have a service that takes data from a database, then collects it into one object and sends it to another service.
The service itself works, but for some reason, after some time, I get the error: `table or view does not exist`.

If the table exists in every schema, What could be causing this error?

```
PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [

    select /*+ index ( a idx_claim_list) */ 
      ... 
    ]; 
    nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

**I have 4 such services and each of them has a timer.**

```
@Service
public class AlterSession {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

        public void alterSession(String branch) {
        try {
            String schemaName = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT schema_name FROM list_market WHERE branch = ?", String.class, branch);  
            jdbcTemplate.execute("ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = " + schemaName);
            jdbcTemplate.execute("CALL MARKET.OPEN()");
            jdbcTemplate.execute("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT ='dd.mm.yyyy'");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("alterSessionException: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}

@Slf4j
@Service
@Scope("singleton")
public class ClaimService {

@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Autowired
private AlterSession alterSession;


    public ClaimRequest getClaim(String branch, Long id) {

            AtomicReference<ClaimRequest> claimRequest = new AtomicReference<>(new ClaimRequest());
            AtomicReference<String> subType = new AtomicReference<>("");
            AtomicReference<String> clientId = new AtomicReference<>("");
            AtomicReference<String> claimType = new AtomicReference<>("");

            try {
                alterSession.alterSession(branch);
                log.info(branch +" -> "+ String.valueOf(id));
                jdbcTemplate.query("select /*+ index ( a idx_claim_list) */ 
                                      ... from table1 a, table2 p", (ResultSet rs) -> {

                    subType.set(rs.getString("type"));
                    clientId.set(rs.getString("id_c"));
                    claimType.set(rs.getString("CLAIM_TYPE"));

                    claimRequest.set(new ClaimRequest(
                            rs.getString("CLAIM_TYPE") == null ? "1" : "5",
                            new BrokerInfo(
                                    "FB29763-23-132",
                                    branch                                
                            ),
                            new ClaimInfo(                                
                                    rs.getString("ID"),
                                    claimType.get()
                            ),
                            new ScoreInfo(
                                    subType.get(),
                                    (claimType.get().equals("01")) ? rs.getString("SCORE_TYPE") : "",
                                    rs.getString("CURRENCY"),
                                    rs.getString("AMOUNT"),
                                    (claimType.get().equals("01") || claimType.get().equals("02")) ? rs.getString("RATE") : null,
                                    rs.getString("PERIOD"),
                                    (claimType.get().equals("01")) ? new String[]{rs.getString("TARGET")} : null
                            )                       
                    ));

                }, id, branch);          


                return claimRequest.get();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error(branch + "-" + id + " " + e.getMessage());
                if (jdbcTemplate.update("UPDATE list_claim SET state = 5 WHERE branch = ? and id = ?", branch, id) == 0) {
                    jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO list_claim (branch, id, state) VALUES (?,?,5) ", branch, id);
                }            
                return null;
            }
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 180000)
    public void claim() {

        List<String> branches = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("SELECT branch FROM list_market", String.class);

        branches.forEach(branch -> {
            try {
                alterSession.alterSession(branch);

                List<Long> claimList = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select id from claim_list where branch = ? where state = 1", Long.class, branch);

                claimList.parallelStream().forEach(x -> {                
                    try {
                        ClaimRequest claimRequest = getClaim(branch, x);
                        
                        .....
                        
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                    }
                });

            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: have you checked that the table exists in the database, the user used by jdbc for the queries has permissions on this table, and if the schema selected when performing the query is the correct one?